# How to move the API calls to server side from a working browser side website?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using javascript to make a POST request, and it works fine when I open my `index.html` file in the **browser** and click on the 'POST' button that I have linked to the following code. However, I would like to move this to **server side** and due to the numerous posts online I am confused as to how to do that? Any help is appreciated.

This is my working js code which returns the values in JSON format

```
const sendRequest = (method, url, data) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
      "accessToken",
      "AB 1234"
    );

    xhr.setRequestHeader("requestId", "req");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("deviceId", "dev");
    xhr.responseType = "json";

    if (data) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status >= 400) {
        reject(xhr.response);
      } else {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject("Something went wrong!");
    };

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
  return promise;
};
```

Comment: nodejs don't have `XHR` take a look at node documentation https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html or better even https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Would I have to change my entire structure then :( ?

Comment: Things you can do on Front-end you can't do on back-end visa versa different technologies. They are apples and oranges. + XHR is outdated now if you want to do HTTP requests use `fetch` for front-end or a library like `axios`. You can use `axios` package in `nodejs` server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how your server connects to your front-end, is it through an API? Is it react? So I'm giving you the most basic answer I could think of, but try to bring more details.

I'm assuming you already have a nodejs server ready to make this request. 
The XMLHttpRequest belongs to browser's API and you can'y use it in Node.js, but there are two ways to do it:
 1. Use the Node.js HTTP api
 2. Use a lib

I think is very important to know how the HTTP api works, but I'm giving you the short answer using a lib called Axios.

```
const axios = require('axios')

const sendRequest = (method, url, data) => {
 axios({
   method,
   url,
   data
 })
}
```

Comment: yes it is an API call as I mentioned in the title, however I don't have a nodejs server ready. Should I do that since one of the commenters said I can't even use XHR in nodejs?

Comment: @new_hello_world yes! this is the first think you should do. If you're not familiar with node, there's a framework called Express that makes it very easy to create a server.

Comment: thanks! I'm also confused as to what the purpose of axios is? does it convert xhr to http?

Comment: Ok, so I told you that Node has a HTTP api, right? It works like XMLHttpRequest, but on the server-side. The problem with the HTTP api is that it is verbose, you have to write too much code. So someone created libs like Axios that runs on top of HTTP, but it's more easy for us to write. Look the difference between your code and mine. Mine is way shorter and easy to understand, right? If I was not using axios, my code would be as big as yours.

Answer (score 0):

As stated node does not have `XHR`, but you should be able to re-implement the request without a great deal of effort by using a request

node-fetch resource: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch

Example Request:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const body = {a: 1};

fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: hi, is 'https://httpbin.org/post' the url of my API? and do I put all my headers such as the  xhr.setRequestHeader("requestId", "req"); under headers?

Comment: Yes you can replace `'httpbin.org/post'` with the API you want to request. You can add all your request headers to the `headers` JSON object.